# Math Probability Discrete Random

Tags: probability

The discrete random variable $X$ has only $2$ possible values $x_1$ and $x_2$, $x_1<x_2$. Find the distribution law of variable $X$, if $P(X=x_1)=0.7$, $M(X)=1.2$ and $D(X)=3.36$
How to start?

Comment: What exactly is meant by $M(X)$ and $D(X)$ here?

Comment: M and D refer to expectation and variance respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two equations with two unknowns.

$0.7x_1+0.3x_2=1.2$

$0.7(x_1-1.2)^2+0.3(x_2-1.2)^2=3.36$